# how to select the content of a focused text

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `<input type="text" value="Hi! Enter Here" >`

How to open this in selected mode and cursor on the input field.

We just start writting into it

Comment: You mean something like http://api.jquery.com/focus/ ?

Comment: Is this question incomplete?  Regardless, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse

Comment: Please be sure your users would appreciate this auto-focus behaviour, I recall *loathing* Google's search page as my home-page simply because I'd start typing with the caret in the address bar and find at least half the characters of the URL in the search box...

Answer (score 2):

use jquery `focus()` function

`$('input').focus();`

Or better

`<input type="text" value="Hi! Enter Here" id="someid">`

and

`$('#someid').focus();`

check working example [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/csx2s/1/).

For **select** and focus

`$('#someid').focus().select();`

or

`$('#someid').focus(function (){$(this).select();});`

On [**jsfiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/csx2s/5/)

Comment: But My input field will not be selected.

Comment: I want focus + select not only focus. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input").focus();
```

Read more at http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Answer (score 1):

Set the id of the input

```
<input type="text" id="myText" value="Hi! Enter Here" >
```

Then add this jQuery

```
$(function() {
  $("#myText").focus();
});
```